# Open source augmented reality framework for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, augmented-reality

Anyone know any open source framework for augmented reality in BlackBerry or a good tutorials for creating an augmented reality application from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an interface prototype for the free LayarPlayer for third party BlackBerry7 apps: https://gist.github.com/1219438. Not sure if Wikitude will have a lib or not.

If you wanna roll your own AR lib (not recommended, unless you have tons of time and energy) OpenGL ES is platform independent, just use ComponentCanvas for overlaying it on top of the camera view.

Answer (score 1):

BlackBerry OS 7 SDK apparently includes APIs to assist in [developing augmented reality applications](http://www.blackberrycool.com/2011/05/31/developers-rim-introduces-blackberry-java-sdk-7-0-beta-for-augmented-reality-nfc-and-more/).

Comment: Thanks Richard for the reply, I went through the sample projects provided with Blackberry 7.0 SDK. I am working on a project where i want to overlay a GLField on camera, then Add different OpenGL objects like triangle, cube, bitmap images to indicate different places according to Lat-Lon, which i have done. But i am not able to render text in OpenGL and map real world coordinates provided by magnetometer to OpenGl 3D world. I just started on OpenGL ES and finding it difficult as there no good blackberry OpenGL tutorial or i am not able to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on an OpenGL application for BlackBerry and I too have realised there are not many OpenGL tutorials for it. But you can always use Android ones. They are not really very different.

And I think we should profit from the new BlackBerry graphics card and CPU to create some exciting 3D application for the patform.

You can find OpenGL basic samples on the BlackBerry website and in the BlackBerry SDK.

Notice: All BlackBerry devices that run on Os 7 have a dedicated graphics card and 1.2ghz of CPU frequency.