# How to implement Augmented reality in Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, augmented-reality

Actually I have a task related to augmented reality and it needs to be implemented on BlackBerry.

Where to start with this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[RIM OS 7 supports augmented reality](http://www.rim.com/products/blackberry_os7.shtml)

Check this publication: [Create Your Own Augmented Reality World: Introducing myWorld by Wikitude](http://blogs.blackberry.com/2012/03/myworld-wikitude-video/)

and this thread: [Open source augmented reality framework for BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088977/open-source-augmented-reality-framework-for-blackberry)